# Change Mac help shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I'd like to change the shortcut (shift + command + question mark) which opens the "Help" tab of the menu bar.
I've found options for change that (keyboard - shortcuts) but there I can't find that shortcut.

Comment: you will need something like karabiner, a 3rd-party remapper / keyboard shortcut to do this. I will leave someone else to answer about those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Keyboard > App Shortcuts…

[image]